# IndexedDB getAll() ordering

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, indexeddb, opera-extension

I'm using `getAll()` method to get all items from db.

```
db.transaction('history', 'readonly').objectStore('history').getAll().onsuccess = ...
```

My `ObjectStore` is defined as:

```
db.createObjectStore('history', { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true });
```

**Can I count on the ordering of the items I get?** Will they always be sorted by primary key `id`?
(or is there a way to specify sort explicitly?)

I could not find any info about ordering in official [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBIndex/getAll)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the docs don't help, consult the specs:

1. [getAll](https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#dom-idbindex-getall) refers to "steps for retrieving multiple referenced values"
2. [the retrieval steps](https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#steps-for-retrieving-multiple-referenced-values-from-an-index) refer to "first *count* records in *index*"
3. [the specification of *index*](https://w3c.github.io/IndexedDB/#index-concept) contains the following paragraph:

   > The records in an index are always sorted according to the record's
   >   key. However unlike object stores, a given index can contain multiple
   >   records with the same key. Such records are additionally sorted
   >   according to the index's record's value (meaning the key of the record
   >   in the referenced object store).

Reading backwards: An index is sorted. `getAll` retrieves the first N of an index, i.e. it is order-preserving. Therefore the result itself should retain the sort order.

Comment: Not only index. ObjectStore is also sorted.